# How to access the pixel data that is displayed on screen?

Tags: 12.04, display

I would like to monitor what's displayed on my screen. For exemple suppose I want to make my screen wobbly (trembling like hell). THen my idea is to access the data about pixels that are supposed to be displayed, then modify their coordinates, then sending them back to the display image queue.
Perhaps it's not working that way at all, I don't know?
Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A part of normally working display window can be captured by

```
 scrot -s SCR_IMG.png
```

, clicking and draggging the mouse to surround a desired part of the display by a rectangle. The

```
 SCR_IMG.png
```

file then contains the captured part.